# MacBook Pro 2018 - Camera not Working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, mojave

When I try FaceTime, Zoom or whatever it does not work. When I open FT, the following message appears "FaceTime has not received any video from the connected camera. Restarting your computer may fix this issue."

I have tried basically `sudo` command, downgrade to Mojave from Catalina, rebooting, etc...

Something interesting I noticed is that in Activity Monitor, VDCAssistant REFUSES to die. Every time I "forcequit" or `sudo` kill it it just create a new PID. This is weird because I checked for Zombie processes and it does not appears there.

Comment: System Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Camera - are the apps listed & checked in there?

Comment: @Tetsujin Camera is not in the left hand category list on my High Sierra MacBook Pro 2017.

Comment: @okhobb - that's because it was new to Mojave, with even more granularity added in Catalina.

Comment: I see. Does that indicate this is not the cause of the problem in High Sierra in that case?